# Github actions - iOS build IPA with Ionic Capacitor

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, continuous-integration, github-actions, ipa

I'm having a little trouble building my app for iOS, I'm finding a lot of errors that I can't solve.

In particular these ones:

```
- /Users/.../ios/App/App.xcodeproj: error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode (in target 'App' from project 'App')
- /Users/.../ios/App/App.xcodeproj: error: No profiles for 'com.test.app' were found: Xcode could not find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.test.app'. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
```

I tried to define my auth when building my app but it doesn't seem to work.

Here are the different steps I tested, and the stack below for the different problems obtained:

```
      - name: Build and archive app
        run: |
          xcodebuild clean archive \
            -workspace ./ios/App/App.xcworkspace \
            -scheme App \
            -archivePath App.xcarchive \
            -sdk iphoneos \
            -configuration Release \
            -allowProvisioningUpdates \
            -authenticationKeyID ${{ secrets.APPLE_KEY_ID }} \
            -authenticationKeyIssuerID ${{ secrets.APPLE_ISSUER_ID }}

      - name: Create IPA file
        run: |
          xcodebuild -exportArchive \
            -archivePath App.xcarchive \
            -exportOptionsPlist ExportOptions.plist \
            -exportPath App.ipa
```

```
Prepare packages

Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs

Create build description
Build description signature: b29c5da4537def559c2a90a0578bc2b7
Build description path: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dncrklogshztwldriuocnjmqfnso/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XCBuildData/b29c5da4537def559c2a90a0578bc2b7-desc.xcbuild

note: Building targets in dependency order
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Copy XCFrameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
/Users/.../ios/App/App.xcodeproj: error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode (in target 'App' from project 'App')
/Users/.../ios/App/App.xcodeproj: error: No profiles for 'com.test.app' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.test.app'. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Copy XCFrameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Copy XCFrameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'GoogleUserMessagingPlatform' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Copy XCFrameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' from project 'Pods')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

If you got these same issues and managed to overcome them, I ask for your help please!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a apple developer account. After that is done, open the project in xcode and go to the signing and capabilities tab. In the signing section, add that developer account you just created. It will configure itself and it should be working. More info can be found at ionic docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios

Comment: It worked when I was working directly on macbook, as you just told me, but I want to do it with Github Actions, and I don't see how I can connect in command line